# ООП в JavaScript.

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Возьмем некую функцию:

```
function DT.operators.Select(body, selectFrame, parentDiv) {
    this.body = body;
    this.selectFrame = selectFrame;
    this.parentDiv = parentDiv;
}
```

Ее можно вызвать двумя способами:

```
DT.operators.Select(op1, op2, op3);
// и
var x = new DT.operators.Select(op1, op2, op3);
```

И возникает вопрос: какая разница, кроме того, что во втором случае переменной передается указатель на функцию?
*UPD1*:
  Как можно делать сокрытие полей и функций?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во втором случае создается переменная - объект класса, с которой можно в дальнейшем работать.
В первом случае все действия заканчиваются на первой строке.

```
function DT.operators.Select(body, selectFrame, parentDiv) {
  this.body = body;
  var somePrivateVar = 'value';//приватное свойство. Аналогично объявляются приватные методы
  this.selectFrame = selectFrame;
  this.parentDiv = parentDiv;
  this.myfunc = function(){
    alert('hello world');
    return this;//Обратите внимание
  }
  this.myfunc2 = function(){
    alert('good-bye world');
    return this;//Обратите внимание
  }
  return this;//Обратите внимание
}
DT.operators.Select(op1, op2, op3).myfunc().myfunc2();//Все. В дальнейшем, доступ к этому объекту отсутствует.

var x = new DT.operators.Select(op1, op2, op3);
x.myfunc();
//some code
x.myfunc2(); //Мы и дальше можем издеваться над этим иксом
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, небольшой пример для наглядности и небольшое объяснение. И еще: можно ли делать сокрытие полей?

Comment: Привел пример.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Хорошее объяснение.

Comment: Держу пари, сейчас припрется синий слоник и опять вывесит простое и понятное объяснение из 3 строчек. =///